# Basic discrete combinatorics questions I have problems with

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

We just started learning counting and I'm very confused. Every question I get is met with a lot of thinking and I still don't get "it". Can I get some help with the following question?

A password consists only small letters a,…,z

a. How many different passwords of sizes greater than 17 and lower than 20 are there?

**My answer** - This one is easy enough. The alphabet is 26 so the amount is $26^{18}$ * $26^{19}$ = $26^{37}$

b. How many passwords of length 8 in which there are at least two different consecutive letters are there?

**My answer** - I believe this one is all of the possibilities except the 26 possibilities of 8 times a, 8 times b, etc... $26^8-26$

c. How many passwords are there of length 8 in which after a letter appears it cannot be written again in the next two places after it (meaning: a letter cannot repeat consecutively, and cannot repeat after skipping just one letter)?

**My answer** - pretty sure about this one. $26*25*24^6 $

d. How many possibilities are there to put in a hat two identical folded notes such that on
one of them is a password of length 6 and on the other a password of length 7, such that no letter repeats twice (not on the same note, and not between the two notes)? Is
the answer different when the notes are of different colors? Explain.

**My answer** - This is where I have a lot of confusion. I eventually came to the conclusion that the answer is not different when the notes are of different colors. The number I got is $8 *10 *37! = 80*37!$

e. How many possibilities are there to put in a hat two identical folded notes such that on
one of them is a password of length 14 and on the other a password of length 15, such
that no letter repeats twice (not on the same note, and not between the two notes)?

No idea what to do here. help?

f. How many possibilities are there to put in a hat two identical folded notes such that on
each of them is a password of length 6, and no letter appears twice (not on the same
note, and not between the two notes)? Is the answer different when the notes are of
different colors? Explain.

No idea what to do here. help?

g. How many possibilities are there to put in a hat two identical folded notes such that on
each of them is a password of length 6? Is the answer different when the notes are of
different colors? Explain.

No idea what to do here. help?

Comment: Your answer to (a) is slightly off.  You are correct that there are $26^{18}$ possible 18 character passwords and $26^{19}$ possible 19 character passwords, but the total number of such passwords should be the sum of these two quantities, not the product.

Comment: I don't understand (b).  Do you mean the number of passwords where the number of letters which appear in consecutive positions in the password is at least 2.  So for example $aabcdefg$ and $aabcaade$ would not be allowed, but $aabbcdef$ and $aabcaaade$ would?

Comment: If part (b) is intended to be interpreted as "A password $a_1a_2a_3\dots a_n$ is "valid" so long as there is some $i$ for which $a_i\neq a_{i+1}$ and invalid otherwise" then you are correct that the invalid passwords consist only of a single letter and your count is correct.  It is not perfectly clear whether or not this is the intended interpretation.

Comment: Part (c) is correct.  Part (d) however, I do not see how you came up with any of the numbers used.  Think of it in this way... make a password of length 13 with no repeated letters and write it on a single piece of paper.  Cut the paper so that the left piece gets six of the letters and the right piece gets the remaining seven letters.  How many ways can this be accomplished?  Convince yourself that the outcomes of the process I describe match exactly with the outcomes described in the original wording of the problem.  Convince yourself that you can tell the notes apart by size without color.

Comment: Part (e) is an identical explanation to (d).  Part (f) however, notice that the two passwords are now of the same length, not different lengths.  so the two notes being (abcdef)(ghijkl) is considered the same outcome as (ghijkl)(abcdef), so doing the "paper cutting" explanation, both abcdefghijkl and ghijklabcdef which would ordinarily have been counted twice should only have been counted once.  Using different colors however $\color{red}{(abcdef)}\color{blue}{(ghijkl)}$ is infact different than $\color{red}{(ghijkl)}\color{blue}{(abcdef)}$.  Color the left half of the cut paper red.

Comment: Thank you for your effort :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a. As mentioned by @Unwisdom, you should sum the number of possible passwords of length 18 and 19, rather than multiply them.

b. This is phrased somewhat poorly, but your interpretation seems correct.

c. Your answer is correct.

d. You have 26 total letters, and will be using 13 of them. How many ways can you choose this? Next, consider how many ways you can arrange these 13 letters, and a procedure for constructing a 6-letter password and a 7-letter password. See the comment made by @JMoravitz for elaboration on the second part. As for the colors, you are correct in saying the answer doesn't change, as the passwords are of two different lengths.

e. You have 26 letters, and need to choose 29 distinct letters to create your two passwords. Is this possible?

f. See a comment made by @JMoravitz for this.

g. Note that now, you can repeat letters. When creating each password of length 6, you have 26 options per letter. Therefore, there are $26^6$ options for password 1, and $26^6$ options for password 2. As the passwords are the same length, coloring them will increase the count.

Comment: I see now. It is 26!/13! for d and not possible in any way for e. Thanks